# Using Interrupt method

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

```
public class TwoThreads {
        private static Object resource = new Object();

        private static void delay(long n) {
            try 
            { 
                Thread.sleep(n);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.print("StartMain ");
            new Thread1().start();
            delay(1000);                       //dealay 1
            Thread t2 = new Thread2();
            t2.start();   
            delay(1000);                      // delay 2    
            t2.interrupt();                   //step 7
            delay(1000);                      //delay 3
            System.out.print("EndMain ");
        }

        static class Thread1 extends Thread {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (resource) {
                    System.out.print("Startl ");
                    delay(6000);
                    System.out.print("End1 ");
                }
            }
        }

        static class Thread2 extends Thread {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (resource) {
                    System.out.print("Start2 ");
                    delay(2000);
                    System.out.print("End2 ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

At step 7 (as I have marked), main thread calls `interrupt()` on thread `t2`, but as it was waiting to acquire the lock on a resource, it doesn't throw any exception. After that, main thread prints "`End Main`" after waiting 1000 ns. In other words, main thread has completed its task, so what triggers `t2.interrupt()` again because it throws exception after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how your program runs, with timestamps:

```
0000 StartMain 
0000 Startl 
3000 EndMain 
6000 End1 
6000 Start2 
6000 End2
```

Why (timestamps in brackets)?

- [0000] main launches Thread1, which acquires a lock and sleeps for 6 seconds
- [1000] main launches Thread2, which can't acquire the lock held by Thread1 for 6 seconds
- [2000] main interrupts Thread2 setting its interrupted flag to true, but Thread2 is waiting for a lock and does not do anything about it
- [3000] main ends
- [6000] Thread1 finishes sleeping and releases the lock
- [6000] Thread2 can acquire it and starts to sleep (its interrupted flag is still on)
- [6000] sleep detects that Thread2 has been interrupted and throws an exception immediately
- [6000] Thread2 finishes, allowing the JVM to exit

Answer (score 1):

You need a `ReentrantLock`.

```
public class TwoThreads {
  private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  private static void delay(long n) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(n);
    } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("StartMain ");
    new Thread1().start();
    delay(1000);                       //dealay 1
    Thread t2 = new Thread2();
    t2.start();
    delay(1000);                      // delay 2    
    t2.interrupt();                   //step 7
    delay(1000);                      //delay 3
    System.out.print("EndMain ");
  }

  static class Thread1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
      try {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
          System.out.print("Startl ");
          delay(6000);
          System.out.print("End1 ");
        } finally {
          lock.unlock();
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // Interrupted.
      }
    }

  }

  static class Thread2 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
      try {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
          System.out.print("Start2 ");
          delay(2000);
          System.out.print("End2 ");
        } finally {
          lock.unlock();
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // Interrupted.
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Prints:

```
StartMain Startl EndMain End1
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s because the JVM kills your threads when the main thread is shutting down.

Comment: they're not daemon threads, they won't get killed when the main thread finishes.